# how to fix { Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.} in richtextbox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show a large text file in richtextbox and I use backgroundworker in my program for escape from deadlock.
When I run program  value of this line
`this.txtText.Text += text + "\r\n";`
is
`{Text = Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.}`
I think that richtextbox can't load my file.
What should i do?

```
private void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath.Text);
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        this.SetText(line);
    }
}

private void SetText(string text)
{
    if (this.txtText.InvokeRequired)
    {
        txtText.Invoke((ThreadStart)(() => SetText(text)));
    }
    else
    {
     this.txtText.Text += text + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add more information to your question?

Comment: richtextbox can't load whole my text file.my text file is 25mb .when  i debug my program , richtextbox don't show my text and my program don't complete.i use break all in it and find that in line of richtexebox  one thing is wrong

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker` uses a seperate thread for processing; generally you do not update ui inside `DoWork` handler.

You need to complete all the background processing in `DoWork` function and wait for `RunWorkerCompleted` to be called. 
You need to use `RunWorkerCompleted` to update ui.

```
    private void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"txtPath.Text");

    }

    private void bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            this.txtText.Text += (line + "\r\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i do your way but richtextbox don't load whole file again

Answer (score 0):

I find out that my problem has nothing to do with richtextbox. i change data structure and use list structure instead of array and string builder so  all things fixed.

```
        StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();

private void bgworker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string line=lines[i];
            list.Add(line);
        }

        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            strb.Append(s);
        }
        txtText.Text = strb.ToString();

    }
```